# How can I delete a repository in the new Bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

The [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Delete+a+repository) is out of date

The new interface does not have the configuration button: [image]

Comment: In left bottom corner you have the Settings button

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a third party web service user support.

Comment: @Juhana [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) *software tools commonly used by programmers* <-

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Log into your Bitbucket account. Navigate to the repository you want to delete. Click the repository's  settings icon. Choose Delete Repository from the left-hand navigation. The system displays the deletion dialog.

[image]

Comment: This is completely off-topic and I apologize for this, but could you tell me how you created this awesome gif?

Comment: I used a software called LICEcap on Mac.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like they have a Windows version as well.

Comment: I was a member of Repository created by other persons on BitBucket. But now, I don't want to show this repository on my BitBucket Account. So, how I can delete this repository on my BB Account ?

Comment: Got it, We have the option of Leave Team to remove the repository in my BB account. Just want to answer as this problem might faced by others also. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Version 2021 - navigate to the repository. In the left menu `Repository settings` and in the top right corner, there is the `Manage repository` dropdown menu with the option to delete the repository.

[image: Delete repository menu]

Answer (score 3):

Version 2016:

```
Select your repo
Click the settings (last one in the left menus)
Scroll down the 'repository details' page
Click the 'delete repository' button on the right.
```

Answer (score 2):

Navigate to the repository you want to delete; click the repository's settings icon. You must see the **manage repository** drop-down button on the right page click on this button and select **Delete repository** option.

**Notic**:
If you can't see that because you state on wrong tab on the left sidebar, so you should choose **Repository details** on the left sidebar, then You will be able to see **manage repository** drop-down button on the right-hand screen. Click that and select **Delete repository** option.

Comment: this is still current Jan 2021 https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/delete-a-repository/

Answer (score 1):

```
UserName/Project >> Setting >> Delete Repository >>  Delete Repository
```